# Multiple realtime database firebase in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make an application that sets a value on the real-time databases(RTDB) but not only one database.
User can insert new RTDB(create RTDB on firebase.google.com and insert api key or something like this in my app) and set value on some key.
**Now the problem 'How to remote to the database in flutter.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the free `Spark Plan`, you are permitted only one RTDB per PROJECT, with a maximum of 100 simultaneous connections to this database, vs on the `Pay As You Go Plan` , you can have multiple RTDBs per PROJECT, with up to 200K connections. Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

edit 1[after comments from OP]

Your best option would be to upgrade to the Blaze plan, it doesn't cost anything upfront, and you also get the free tier benefits. i.e 1 GB stored & 10 GB downloaded monthly per database, then you are billed based on your usage.

But if you are going to have multiple users, then it'd be worth paying for more. Also, if you have more than 100 users, you will have to upgrade anyway. But 1 GB stored per database, is a respectable amount for an IOT service. If you are trying to run a business, the smart thing would be is to upgrade, besides making your life easier while writing code. Firebase have generous free plan offers for starters, but if you are racking up money, it's worth every penny you pay, because in theory, you won't have to pay, unless you have so much users that the free plan isn't enough anymore, and isn't that everybody's dream? When the free plan isn't enough?

Disclaimer, I DO NOT WORK FOR GOOGLE or have any benefit for advertising this besides from business logic and previous personal experience.

Comment: oh sorry it is my fault.I mean it will have many app there( May be more than one PROJECT).
for example, first app for IOT and another one for chat app but i just want to control all of these in my application

Comment: so I need to redirect to other apps (maybe other PROJECT) so this is what I want.

Comment: Your best option would be to upgrade to the Blaze plan, it doesn't cost anything upfront, and you also get the free tier benefits. i.e 1 GB stored & 10 GB downloaded per database, then you are billed based on your usage. But if you are going to have multiple users, then it'd be worth it to pay for more. Also, if you have more than 100 users, you will have to upgrade anyway. But 1 GB stored per database, is a respectable amount for an IOT service.
If you are trying to run a business, the smart thing would be is to upgrade, besides making your life easier. 
Disclaimer, I DO NOT WORK FOR GOOGLE